# Dynamic length of generic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I've written a method that gets an array of objects, the types of the array contents as generics and tries to cast each type to the delivered generic:

```
    public static void GetMultipleObjectsFromParameters<T, U>(
        object parameterArray, out T parameter1, out U parameter2)
    {
        parameter1 = default(T);
        parameter2 = default(U);

        try
        {
            object[] arr = parameterArray as object[];

            if (arr == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("array not valid");
                return;
            }
            if (arr.Length != 2)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("arr.Length != 2");
                return;
            }

            parameter1 = (T)arr[0];
            parameter2 = (U)arr[1];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Write(ex);
        }
    }
```

I thought this method could be very useful if I use a BackgroundWorker and want to deliver more than one argument of different types (e.g. first parameter as string, second as integer...).

Now I've just wondered if there is a way to write this method without forcing a fixed size of parameters. This would prevent me from writing a method like this for each count of parameters.

I hope the question was comprehensible. Is there an easy approach? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if there is a way to write this method without forcing a fixed size of parameters

You don't need to write this method with variable size of parameters. You need [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
        var myParams = Tuple.Create(100, "Hello, world!");
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var arg = (Tuple<int, string>)args.Argument;
            if (arg.Item2.Length > 5)
            {
                var foo = arg.Item1 + 200;
            }

            // etc ...
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync(myParams);
```

or [lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) with closures:

```
        var someIntParam = 100;
        var someStringParam = "Hello, world!";

        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (someStringParam.Length > 5)
            {
                var foo = someIntParam + 200;
            }

            // etc ...
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

It depends on how do you use `BackgroundWorker` in your real code.

Comment: How would you propose to do this in a generic way without multiple methods of different arities?

Comment: @JonSkeet: OP mentioned `BackgroundWorker`. I suppose, all that he needs is to pass some parameters to worker's delegate.

Comment: Well he mentioned that as one use case... but the way I read the question was whether that method could be written more generally.

Comment: You're right, I only use this method for "unwrap" delivered parameters in a background worker.
Do you've an example how I might achieve this with Tuples and Lambdas?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't think, that this question must be read literally. :) but this is only my assumption.

Comment: @Dennis Great, the lambda with closures method convinced me.
I didn't knew that this is possible in C#.

Comment: @Dennis: Looks like you were right :) Will leave my answer up, but edit it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: This answer addresses the original question rather than the motivation behind it. In terms of passing work to a `BackgroundWorker` etc, using a lambda expression makes perfect sense.

> Now I've just wondered if there is a way to write this method without forcing a fixed size of parameters.

Nope, I'm afraid not. What you're looking for is higher order types, I *think*<sup>1</sup> - but they don't exist in .NET (which is why there are so many "generic arity overloads" for `Func<>`, `Tuple<>`, `Action<>` etc).

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't know much about these things myself, to be honest. Joe Duffy has a [blog post](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/11/04/LongingForHigherkindedC.aspx) which blows my mind somewhat, but which may be useful.

Comment: sorry Jon off topic maybe, which language supports higher order types? hadn't heard of them before.

Comment: Great and fast answer, thank you. Can you maybe explain shortly what these "higher order types" are? I've never heard about that until now.

Comment: @PhilippEger: I can't say I know much about them myself. You might find http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/11/04/LongingForHigherkindedC.aspx useful though.